# How to solve error: invalid path 'completion.bash.' when pulling branch?

Tags: git, github

I pull from another branch with :

```
git pull origin toetra.
```

And this is the error:

```
* branch              toetra     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: invalid path 'completion.bash.'
Updating 33f32610..a7976185
```

Comment: This message is due to the fact that you're on Windows, which does not like a file name ending with a period like that. Use some other OS to check out the commit, rename the file, commit the result, and push that back to the source, and then you'll be able to extract the file on Windows. Or, ignore the error if you don't actually need the file.

Comment: @torek Using docker is a solution?

Comment: It might be. I don't use Windows myself and on my mac, when I have issues like this, I either use a case-sensitive file system or spin up a virtual machine and run Linux in the VM. VMs are "heavier weight" than Docker in general but if I had a Windows image, I could run Windows in the VM, which I don't think I can do in Docker on my mac (though I haven't tried).

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your git configuration setting to default ones. by using `git config --global --unset`. otherwise you can search for `~/.gitconfig` using for favourate vim editor, look for `completion.bash` and update it.